# Show by induction that $n! > n \cdot F_n$ for all $n > 3$

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial, fibonacci-numbers

Show by induction that $n! > n \cdot F_n$ for all $n> 3$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th fibonacci number.

For the basis step, I put $n=4$ and got:
\begin{align*}
&4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 24 \\
&4 \cdot F_4 = 4 \cdot 3 = 12
\end{align*}
So the statement holds for $n=4$. For the inductive step, we assume the statement holds for a $k > 3$, and checks for $n = k+1$. We have:
\begin{align*}
&(k+1)! = (k+1)\cdot k \cdot (k-1) \cdot \; \dotsc \; \cdot 1 = (k+1 ) \cdot k!  \\
&(k+1) \cdot F_{k+1} = (k+1)(F_k + F_{k-1}) = k \cdot F_k +  k\cdot F_{k-1} + F_{k} + F_{k-1}
\end{align*}
By the induction assumption, we know that
\begin{align*}
k\cdot F_k + (k-1) \cdot F_{k-1} < k! + (k-1)! \leq k! + k! < 2k! <(k+1)k!,
\end{align*}
But we see that 
\begin{align*}
k\cdot F_k + (k-1) \cdot F_{k-1}  < (k+1) \cdot F_{k+1},
\end{align*}
so we can't really say if $(k+1) \cdot F_{k+1}$ is less than $(k+1)!$ or not.

Does this mean that the statement is not true, or is there just a better way of proving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following way?

It is sufficient to prove that $(n-1)!\gt F_n$ for $n\gt 3$.

Inductive step : we assume that $(k-1)!\gt F_k$.

Then, multiplying the both sides by $k$ gives
$$k!\gt kF_k\gt F_k+F_k\gt F_k+F_{k-1}=F_{k+1}$$

Comment: First of all, why is it sufficient to show $(n-1)! > F_n$?.  And second off all, you only show $k! > F_{k+1}$ by this method, not $k! > kF_k$.

Comment: (1) Because $(n-1)!\gt F_n$ is equivalent to $n!\gt n\cdot F_n$. (you can divide the both sides of $n!\gt n\cdot F_n$ by $n$.) (2) When $n=k+1$, $(n-1)!\gt F_n$ becomes $k!\gt F_{k+1}$ which is what we have to prove assuming that $(k-1)!\gt F_k$.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thank you so much for specifying.

Comment: @SBS: You are welcome.